# My code is not producing anything in Spyder's variable explorer

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Ive written some code that mimics a video game i play and normally you would assume that running anything in the console of spyder would generate viewable variables in the variable explorer, but mine doesnt do that.
Im using Python 3.6 and Spyder 3.3.0.
The variable explorer isnt broken because when i run some dummy code like x=10, it shows up in the variable explorer.

I have tried every single combination of the gear settings found that the top right corner of the variable explorer pane in Spyder. I have tried every version of Spyder available within Anaconda. I have tried using only parts of the code from my program but nothing is showing up when I run it in the console. It used to work fine but that what months ago and I cant remember when I last saw the variable explorer work

The code i longer than 900 lines so here is the beginning of the code and a pastebin link to the full code.

```py
from math import trunc
from math import floor

def Effective_strength_function(
        Strength_level=0, Potion_bonus_input=0, Prayer_bonus_input=0, Style_bonus_input=0,
        S_potion=0, SS_potion=0, Z_potion=0, C_potion=0,
        Burst_of_Strength=0, Superhuman_Strength=0, Ultimate_Strength=0, Chivalry=0, Piety=0, No_prayer=0,
        Aggressive=0, Controlled=0, Accurate=0,
        Other_bonus_input=0,
        Weapon_bonus=0,
            Weapon_bonus_input=0, 
                Weapon=0,
        Armour_bonus=0,
            Armour_bonus_input=0,
                Helmet_bonus_input=0,
                    Helmet_input=0,
                        Helmet=0,
                Amulet_bonus_input=0,
                    Amulet_input=0,
                        Amulet=0,
                Cape_bonus_input=0,
                    Cape_input=0,
                        Cape=0,
                Torso_bonus_input=0,
                    Torso_input=0,
                        Torso=0,
                Gloves_bonus_input=0,
                    Gloves_input=0,
                        Gloves=0,
                Legs_bonus_input=0,
                    legs_input=0,
                        Legs=0,
                Boots_bonus_input=0,
                    Boots_input=0,
                        Boots=0,
                Shield_bonus_input=0,
                    Shield_input=0,
                        Shield=0,
                Ring_bonus_input=0,
                    Ring_input=0,
                        Ring=0,
    Monster_health=0,
    Monster_count=0,
        Monster_count_warning=0,
    Attack_level=0,
    Slayer_task=0,
        Slayer_task_bonus=0
                               ):
```

```
[Pastebin] https://pastebin.com/HQwj2GXj
```

When you run code that has at least one variable in it, it will show up in the variable explorer in Spyder. It will display if something is an intiger, float, list, array etc. Mine stays blank when i run my game code.

Comment: So im now to posting anything on stack overflow and that piece of code is not what it looks like (that i pasted in the description). my apologies.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) All your code seems to be inside your `Effective_strength_function` function (although is hard to tell because it's very long and not clear to read). If that's the case, then it's normal for our variable explorer to not show anything because you effectively have encapsulated your code in that function. In other words, the variable explorer can only show variables created in the global namespace (e.g. when you define `a=10` outside any function, class or method).

Comment: thank you for helping me, im gonna change my code to be more efficient!

Comment: Your code is fine. The only thing is that if you want to see some of its variables in our variable explorer, you need to move it out of that function.